# Totally positive/negative units in preordered rings with bounded inversion

Tags: commutative-algebra, real-algebraic-geometry, ordered-rings

Let $A$ be a preordered ring (or $\mathbb{R}$-algebra or $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra).

Say that ${a \in A}$ is *totally positive* if for every morphism ${f : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}}$ of ordered algebras, ${f a  \geq 0}$.

Define  *totally negativeness* analogously.

To avoid trival cases assume that there is some morphism (of preordered rings)  ${A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}}$.

Assume also that $A$ with bounded inversion (i.e., for any positive ${a \in A}$, ${1 + a}$ is a unit).

Question:  Is it the case that any unit of $A$ is totally positive or totally negative?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "or $\mathbb{R}$-algebra"? An $\mathbb{R}$-algebra can in general not be ordered, so the question would not make sense in that context.

Comment: I meant a preordered ring equipped with a morphism ${\mathbb{R} \rightarrow A}$ of pre-orderered rings.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, morphisms of preordered rings respect positivity but, as far as I can see, there may be units in a preordered ring that are neither positive nor negative. (Also, I meant "totally" when I wrote "strictly"; thanks, I'll correct the post.)

Comment: $A=\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ has two real embeddings $f_1,f_2$ (sending $x$ to $\sqrt2$ or $-\sqrt2$),

the pre-order is $a\ge b$ if $f_1(a-b)\ge 0,f_2(a-b)\ge 0$,

then $x \in A^\times$ but $x $ isn't positive or negative.

Comment: @Boogie oops, I understand now, thank you!